# Is Point Cloud Library compatible with other drivers than OpenNI?

Tags: point-cloud-library

Is point cloud library compatible with other drivers than OpenNI?

Comment: What driver are you looking to use specifically?

Answer (score 1):

In principle it is compatible with any source of points - you just need a way of finding the 3D points coming from the camera data; most "grabbers" are just wrappers around the sensor's own driver/SDK.

You can find a list of grabbers in the main PCL repository here (including stereo):

- http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_image_grabber_base.html

Other sensors often have grabbers made available separately by those who use the sensors. E.g. for DepthSense:

- https://github.com/taketwo/ds
- https://github.com/ph4m/DepthSenseGrabber

Answer (score 1):

Yes, several other drivers offer access to different sensors; as of PCL latest release (1.7.2) these are the following sensors available:

- OpenNI (Kinect, Xtion, Carmine cameras)
- Velodyne grabber
- Dinast grabbert

In addition to the drivers mentioned before the next release (1.8.0) adds new sensors:

- IDS-Imaging Ensenso cameras
- David SLS-2 scanners
- DepthSense cameras

You can find more information about these sensors in the [tutorials](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#i-o) section of the website and in the [documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__io.html).
It is also possible to add any other sensor by adding a grabber in the IO module of the library.

Comment: what for intel realsense?